# Why's _itoa causing my program to crash?

Tags: c

The following code just keeps on crashing when it reaches the part with _itoa, I've tried to implement that function instead and then it got even weirder, it just kept on crashing when I ran it without the debugger but worked fine while working with the debugger.

```
# include "HNum.h"
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <assert.h>
# define  START_value 30


typedef enum {
    HNUM_OUT_OF_MEMORY = -1,
    HNUM_SUCCESS = 0,
} HNumRetVal;

typedef struct _HNum{
    size_t Size_Memory; 
    char* String;
}HNum;

HNum *HNum_alloc(){
    HNum* first = (HNum*)malloc(sizeof(HNum));
    if(first==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    first->String =(char*)malloc(sizeof(START_value));
    if(first->String==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    first->Size_Memory = START_value; // slash zero && and starting from zero index;
    return first;
}

HNumRetVal HNum_setFromInt(HNum *hnum, int nn){
    itoa(nn,hnum->String,10);
}

void main(){
    HNum * nadav ;
    int h = 13428637;
    nadav = HNum_alloc();
    nadav->String="1237823423423434";
    HNum_setFromInt(nadav,h);
    printf("nadav string : %s \n ",nadav->String);
    //printf("w string %s\n",w->String);
    //printf("nadav string %s\n",nadav->String);
    HNum_free(nadav);

}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and couldn't come up with anything...
The IDE I'm using is Visual Studio 2012 express, the crash shows the following:
"PROJECT C.exe has stopped working
windows can check online for a solution to the program."

Comment: C-"string" literals are constant.

Comment: Run it with the debugger and latter will tell you where exactly it crashes. Then tell us.

Comment: @alk There are two errors in the code.  The post you link to covers one of these nicely but doesn't help with the other (`sizeof`) issue.

Comment: Sure, however the question was why it crashes in `itoa()`. @simonc

Answer (score 4):

```
first->String =(char*)malloc(sizeof(START_value));
```

should be

```
first->String = malloc(START_value);
```

The current version allocates space for `sizeof(int)-1` characters (-1 to leave space for the nul terminator).  This is too small to hold your target value so `_itoa` writes beyond memory allocated for `first->String`.  This results in undefined behaviour; it is quite possible for different runs to fail in different places or debug/release builds to behave differently.

You also need to remove the line

```
nadav->String="1237823423423434";
```

which leaks the memory allocated for `String` in `HNum_alloc`, replacing it with a pointer to a string literal.  This new pointer should be considered to be read-only; you cannot write it it inside `_itoa`

Comment: I tried initializing the string with 50 and it'd still crash all the same, and about changing that line of code you mentioned, I suppose that's indeed the correct way to write it, but my code should still work without it, right?

Comment: You need to make both of the changes I noted.  The code will not work reliably without them.

Comment: It won't let me write it like that "first->String = malloc(START_value);" Says that "Error: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"
And changing nadav->String="1237823423423434";  to strcpy(nadav->String, "1237823423423434"); causes this program to crash on the strcpy line too

Comment: Sounds like you're using a C++ compiler on a C project.  If you use a C compiler you won't require the cast.  You'll need to reinstate the `(char*)` cast if you want to continue using a C++ compiler.  Your use of `strcpy` should be fine but is not required.  Are you sure you'd fixed the `malloc` line when you tried this?

Comment: @simonc: The cast won't hurt with a C compiler. And I think it will allocate `sizeof(int)` bytes, not `sizeof(int)-1`

Comment: @AaronDigulla Agreed that the cast is permissible.  I was suggesting it wasn't desirable (Most but not all posts in [should I cast the return from malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/311966) agree that the cast isn't desirable).  I also agree that `sizeof(int)` bytes are allocated.  Since this memory will be used for a nul-terminated string, we need to allocate space for the terminator.  This leaves `sizeof(int)-1` bytes left for output characters.  I'll see if I can reword to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment:

**simonc**'s answer is correct. If you find the following answer useful, you should mark his answer as the right one:P 
I tried that code myself and the only thing missing is lets say:

`strcpy(nadav->String, "1237823423423434");` INSTEAD OF `nadav->String="1237823423423434";`

and

`first->String = malloc(START_value);` INSTEAD OF `first->String =(char*)malloc(sizeof(START_value));`

Also, maybe you'd have to use `_itoa` instead of `itoa`, that's one of the things I had to change in my case anyhow.

If that doesn't work, you should probably consider using a different version of VS.

Comment: The most important part of the `malloc` change is to allocate the correct number of bytes.  `malloc(sizeof(START_value))` will probably give you a 4 byte buffer.  This isn't long enough to hold a textual representation of any integer so isn't an optional part of the fix.  Which is all a roundabout way of saying that the code should (and probably will) *not* work without both changes.

Comment: Oh right, my bad, I meant to write it without the "sizeof" part.
What I meant to say is that "first->String =(char*)malloc(START_value);" would've worked. Or is that the same thing as you wrote?

Comment: Yes, that's the same as I tried to write.  I could obviously have been clearer though :-)